# Why doesn't UtteranceProgress Listener get called on Text to Speech?

Tags: java, android, listener, text-to-speech

I've tried to call some Methods on start and end of text to speech so I used the `setOnUtteranceProgressListener` but it doesn't work/get called.

What am I doing wrong?

Here the needed code:

Class:

```
public class SpeechRecognizerActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
```

Init Method:

```
 @Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        String language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
           
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }
}
```

Method where speaking starts:

```
private void speakOut(String text) {
    setTtsListener();
    tts.setPitch(1.5f);
    tts.setSpeechRate(1.5f);
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

The Listener (Method gets called in speakOut):
None of those logs get displayed in Logcat.

```
private void setTtsListener() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15)
    {
        int listenerResult = tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDone(String utteranceId)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"progress on Done " + utteranceId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String utteranceId)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"progress on Error " + utteranceId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart(String utteranceId)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"progress on Start " + utteranceId);
            }
        });
        if (listenerResult != TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to add utterance progress listener");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int listenerResult = tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"progress on Completed " + utteranceId);
            }
        });
        if (listenerResult != TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to add utterance completed listener");
        }
    }
}
```

A little workaround I found was this:

```
boolean speakingEnd = tts.isSpeaking();
    do {
        speakingEnd = tts.isSpeaking();
    } while ((speakingEnd));
    Log.d(TAG,"talking stopped");
```

I've added it a the end of the `speakOut` method, but this solution isn't very good.
Working with the listeners would be perfect.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TTS-UtteranceProgressListener not being called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296792/tts-utteranceprogresslistener-not-being-called)

Answer (score 33):

When you call `tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);`
You need to pass it a map with the KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID

```
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"messageID");
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);
```

This lets TextToSpeech know to use your utterance listener for that `text`

Comment: Thank you sir. You saved my day! I also forgot to pass map as a parameter of `.speak()` method